# Is my signup form vulnerable to code injections? If so, how do i secure it

Tags: html, node.js, code-injection

Below is a snippet of my signup form that i want to use to store user information when they signup for my service. I want to display their first name when they login, and thus opens up the chance for malicious code running on their web browser. The question is, how do i secure the user input to prevent malicious code from being injected into the input, and then stored on my backend thats running on nodejs? Can you offer me an example?

Here is the client side code for the form

```
    <div class="tab-form">
      <div id="signup">
        <h1>Sign up for the <span>Beta</span></h1>
        <form action="/signup" method="post">
        <div class="top-row">
          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>First Name<span class="req">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" name="f_Name" required autocomplete="off" />
          </div>
          <div class="field-wrap">
            <label>Last Name<span class="req">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" name="l_Name" required autocomplete="off"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label>Email<span class="req">*</span></label>
          <input type="email" name="email" size="64" maxlength="64" required autocomplete="off"/>
        </div>
        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label>Address<span class="req">*</span></label>
          <input type="text" name="address" required autocomplete="off"/>
        </div>
        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label>Address 2</label>
          <input type="text" name="address_2"/>
        </div>
        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label>City<span class="req">*</span></label>
          <input type="text" name="city" required autocomplete="off"/>
        </div>
        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label>Zip code<span class="req">*</span></label>
          <input type="text" name="zip_code" required autocomplete="off"/>
        </div>
        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label>Phone number<span class="req">*</span></label>
          <input type="tel" name="phone_number" required autocomplete="off"/>
        </div>
        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label>Password<span class="req">*</span></label>
          <input type="password" name="password" required autocomplete="off"/>
        </div>
        <div class="button-container">
          <button type="submit" class="button button-block"/>Sign Me Up!</button>
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the server side code that adds the user input value to a database.

```
  passport.use("local-signup", new LocalStrategy({
    // Override username with email for authentication
    usernameField: "email",
    passwordField: "password",
    passReqToCallback: true // Pass the entire request to the callback
  },
  function(req, email, password, done) {

    // Async task
    // User.findOne wont run unless data arrives
    process.nextTick(function() {

      // Find user that matches the email provided on forms
      // Checks for an already existing user that matches the credentials
      User.findOne({ "local.email" : email }, function(err, user) {
        // Return error if one exists
        if(err)
          return done(err);

        // Checks for the existance of a user matching the email provided
        if(user) {
          return done(null, false, req.flash("signupMessage", "Email already used."));
        } else {

          // If user with that email doesnt exists
          // Generate a new user matching that email
          var newUser        = new User();
          var firstname      = req.body.f_Name;
          var lastname       = req.body.l_Name;
          var address        = req.body.address;
          var address2       = req.body.address_2;
          var city           = req.body.city;
          var zipcode        = req.body.zip_code;
          var phonenumber    = req.body.phone_number;
          var passwordHash = newUser.generateHash(password);
          // Adds new credentials
          newUser.local.email        = firstname;
          newUser.local.password     = passwordHash;
          newUser.local.phone_number = phonenumber;
          newUser.local.zip_code     = zipcode;
          newUser.local.city         = city;
          newUser.local.address_2    = address2;
          newUser.local.address      = address;
          newUser.local.l_Name       = lastname;
          newUser.local.f_Name       = firstname;

          // Save new credentials
          newUser.save(function(err) {
            if(err)
              throw err;
            return done(null, newUser);
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

**how do i secure the user input to prevent malicious code from being injected into the input, and then stored on my backend thats running on nodejs?**

Answer: Use validation, but more importantly, escape user input.

---

First of all, you could add validation, eg. you could only allow alphanumerical characters (a-Z and 0-9). However, I think that users should be able to choose their password freely, meaning they should be able to use whatever characters they want. `;DROP TABLE USERS` seems like a fine password to me.

The last thing you want is an SQL injection, so I'd suggest using an ORM system that will bind the user input as parameters into your database queries. You should do this for every query, and especially when the query is built up from user input.